# Cannot implicitly convert type 'MouseEventHandler' to 'RoutedEventHandler

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I tried to inherit method button1_click and I got the message above, how to fix that ?

```
namespace visualinheritance
{
    public partial class usercontrolcommon : UserControl
    {
        public usercontrolcommon()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("usercontrolcommon");
        }
    }
}

namespace visualinheritance
{
    public partial class usercontrol1 : usercontrolcommon
    {
        public usercontrol1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.button1.Click += new MouseEventHandler(button1_Click);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the C# [capitalization convntions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button click event is not a mouse event.  Just change the handler to `button1.Click += button1_Click;` and it will work

Comment: Thanks but now I got a subsequent problem when droping usercontrol1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842494/cannot-create-an-instance-of-usercontrol1